# Create dictionary so different functions have access

Tags: .net, dictionary, scope, c++-cli

Is it possible to declare a dictionary so that different functions, in my case a normal `void` function and a callback, can access that dictionary?

For example:

```
ref class dct {
public:
    static Dictionary<String^, anyID>^ dc = gcnew Dictionary<String^, anyID>();
}
```

and then access that dict from 2 functions, containing the same information?

```
void foo() {
    dct::dc->Add("Foo", 23) // anyID is a uint16
}

void myCallback(Object^ sender, MyCallbackArgs^ e) {
    dct::dc->Add(e.ToString(), 28) 
}
```

So I mean that the Dictionary contains `{"Foo": 23}` and `{"<whatever e is>": 28}` and when I would like to access it from example from a 3rd function it still has those values.

Would that work as I think?
If not, is there a way around that, without using function arguments?

Comment: `Would that work as I think?` Have you tried it?

Comment: Well yea, but it worked with an Int, but not with a dict

Comment: I haven't verified it with a compiler, but it looks like your code will compile as-is. Why not try it?

Comment: Which is why I kinda thought it was weird or a dict related thing